# this is undefined en addEventListener Callback

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom, callback

Hola tengo el siguiente código html:

```
<nav id="myNav" class="nav has-shadow">
    <div class="nav-center">
        <a class="nav-item is-tab is-active">Ingresos</a>
        <a class="nav-item"><h1 id="myTitle" class="title">Letor</h1></a>
        <a class="nav-item is-tab">Gastos</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

y el siguiente js:

```
function startMenu(){
    let menuButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('is-tab');

    for(let i=0; i<menuButtons.length;i++ )
        menuButtons[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(this);
        });
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de acceder a `this` desde el callback o necesariamente tengo que agregar un parámetro en la funcion para buscar el `target`?

Comment: a que callback te refieres?

Comment: @x-rw la que usa el .addEventListener (la función anónima ()=>{})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas usando una [`función flecha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) (En ingles `arrow function`).

> Las funciones de flecha capturan el valor de `this` del contexto actual

### Solución:

Usar una función

Ejemplo:

```js
function startMenu(){
    let menuButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('is-tab');

    for(let i=0; i<menuButtons.length;i++ )
        menuButtons[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log(this);
        });
}
```

```html
<nav id="myNav" class="nav has-shadow" onclick="startMenu(event)">
  <div class="nav-center">
    <a class="nav-item is-tab is-active">Ingresos</a>
    <a class="nav-item">
      <h1 id="myTitle" class="title">Letor</h1>
    </a>
    <a class="nav-item is-tab">Gastos</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente se puede obtener mediante un `target`

```js
function startMenu(e){
     console.log(e.target.nodeName);

}
```

```html
<nav id="myNav" class="nav has-shadow" onclick="startMenu(event)">
    <div class="nav-center">
        <a class="nav-item is-tab is-active">Ingresos</a>
        <a class="nav-item"><h1 id="myTitle" class="title">Letor</h1></a>
        <a class="nav-item is-tab">Gastos</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```